# sgpanel vbar distinguist with fill-pattern within groups of the same colour

Tags: sas

i'm using SAS 9.4 and created a nice bar-chart with sgpanel like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f1l8.png)

The code is as follows:

```
proc sgpanel data=transp_5;
panelby position / layout=columnlattice onepanel
                   colheaderpos=bottom rows=2 novarname noborder;
styleattrs datacolours=(CXbe0a6e CXbe0a6e 
                        CXe17d00 CXe17d00 
                        CXbcc121 CXbcc121 
                        CX3caf7f CX3caf7f 
                        CX0077ad CX0077ad) 
            DATACONTRASTCOLORS=(nocolour);
                        format position order.;
                        format crop_type concatf.; 
vbar crop_type /  group=crop_type response=col1 stat=sum  nostatlabel     
                  barwidth=1 groupdisplay=cluster CLUSTERWIDTH= 1;
colaxis display=none;
rowaxis grid labelattrs =(size=12)  valueattrs=(size=12)   
             label="probability" ;
keylegend  / valueattrs=(size=10) titleattrs=(size=10) AUTOITEMSIZE 
             title="crop group" down=2; 
where time in ("Feb01", "Jul02", "Aug01", "Sep01" ," Okt02" , 
                "Nov01");
run;
```

Wat i want now, is to distinguish between the attributes "Ps" and "Pfw" for the crops (e.g. corn maize with the SAME colour) by using a fill pattern like dashed or something else. 
I found the FILLPATTERNATTRS= options which should work with sgpanelm but it doesn't work so far. 
How can i combine fill colours and fill patterns with sgpanel in SAS 9.4?
Thanks,
Sandra

Comment: Have you tried a data attribute map? I don't have time to work up an example but I think it should work here.

Comment: Which version of SAS are you using ? FILLPATTERNATTRS is new in SAS version 9.4M5.  You might consider using lighter shade of the 'Winter' color for the 'Spring' crops.  The DATTRMAP documentation does not indicate that a FILLPATTERN variable will be processed by SGPANEL.  The documentation shows how to cross hatch a SGPLOT VBAR, but it's not a simple option. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/65235/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0relmtk2s8ac9n13bnmicsgsmwu.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SAS 9.4 and updated to M5 in order to use the fillpatterms, but it didn't work. BUT: i solved it, yeah! See the result here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3U1Q.png) 
i used a style template and modified it a little as follows

```
proc template;                                                                
 define style Styles.meins;                                              
 parent = styles.Journal3; 
  style GraphData1 from GraphData1 /                                      
    fillpattern = "solid";
  style GraphData2 from GraphData2 /                                      
    fillpattern = "L1";                                                  
  style GraphData3 from GraphData3 /                                      
    fillpattern = "solid";                                                 
  style GraphData4 from GraphData4 /                                      
    fillpattern = "L1";                                                  
  style GraphData5 from GraphData5 /                                      
    fillpattern = "solid";                                                  
  style GraphData6 from GraphData6 /                                      
    fillpattern = "L1";                                                  
  style GraphData7 from GraphData7 /                                      
    fillpattern = "solid";                                                  
  style GraphData8 from GraphData8 /                                      
    fillpattern = "L1";                                                  
  style GraphData9 from GraphData9 /                                      
    fillpattern = "solid";                                                  
  style GraphData10 from GraphData10 /                                      
    fillpattern = "L1";                                                  
  style GraphData11 from GraphData11 /                                    
    fillpattern = "solid" ;                                                  
  style GraphData12 from GraphData12 /                                    
    fillpattern = "L1" ;                                                  
  style GraphData13 from GraphData13 /                                    
    fillpattern = "solid";  
  end;
run; 

ods graphics on;
 ods html path ='datasave_path'
 image_dpi=500
 style=meins; quit;
proc sgpanel data=zusammen;
 panelby position/ layout=columnlattice onepanel
                   colheaderpos=top novarname noborder spacing=1;
styleattrs datacolors=(CXbe0a6e CXbe0a6e
                       CXe13f0d CXe13f0d
                       CXe17d00 CXe17d00
                       CXbcc121 CXbcc121
                       CX3caf7f CX3caf7f
                       CX0077ad CX0077ad
                       CXB2B2B2)
DATACONTRASTCOLORS=(black); 
           format position order.;
           format crop_type concatf_a.; 
vbar crop_type /  group=crop_type response=col1 stat=sum  nostatlabel 
                  barwidth=1 groupdisplay=cluster
                  CLUSTERWIDTH=1;
colaxis display=none;
rowaxis grid labelattrs =(size=12)  valueattrs=(size=12)   
             label="probability" GRID VALUES = (0 TO 1 BY 0.1);
keylegend  / valueattrs=(size=10) titleattrs=(size=0) AUTOITEMSIZE 
             title="" down=4 noborder;
 where time in ("Feb01", "Feb02" , "Mar01" , "Mar02" , "Apr01" ); 
run;
```

I didn't trie the attribute map, but this would have been the next step if the style template wouldn't have been working.
Thanks,
Sandra